# Laravel new Model missing created_at and updated_at fields

Tags: laravel, eloquent

When I create a new Model in controller update function with `new Model` it's missing `created_at` and `updated_at`. I therefore get error 409, as it is unable to perform the query. Any idea why those two fields are missing?

```
$branchItem = Branch::where('id', $branch['branchId'])->get()->first();

// if there is no record with branchId create new one
if (!$branchItem) {
    $branchItem = new Branch;
}
$branchItem->id= $branch['branchId'];

$branchItem->save();
```

Comment: Missing means what, not in table or their value is blank in table?

Comment: Missing as they are not in table.

Comment: If you dont have columns in table then, you have to create them with migration or manually,if columns are in table and their values are blank then you have to check if you have this line in model and remove it `$timestamps = false;`

Comment: Sorry I should be more specific. They are in the table in database, but they are not in the $branchItem object, when `new Branch` is created

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also check with the documentation of [Laravel Migration](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations)

And you can also follow below code in your migration file

```
Schema::create('table_name', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->timestamps(); // this field is able to create your created_at and updated_at field in DB.
});
```

So you have to add above code in your migration file placed here **project_folder/database/migrations/migration_file**

Once you add this line you have to run migration command in terminal

```
php artisan migrate:refresh
```

**Note: When you run this command, this will flush your all table's data and reset structure**

Hope this will lead you to resolve problem.

Answer (score 1):

create `created_at` and `updated_at` column manually it's not best practice but it will solve your issue

always use laravel migration to create tabel

```php
  Schema::create('example', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');

            $table->timestamps();

        });
```

here `$table->timestamps();` is responsible to create  those 2 fields

Answer (score 0):

You are missing created_at and updated_at in table take it as a timestamp   and updated_at as NULL

Answer (score 0):

Try changing code like this.

```
$branchItem = Branch::where('id', $branch['branchId'])->first();

// if there is no record with branchId create new one
if (!$branchItem) {
    $branchItem = new Branch;
    $branchItem->id= $branch['branchId'];
    $branchItem->save();
} else {
    echo "Record Exist";
}
```